# Converting color through library doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple conversion with [color.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js) from [this library](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker). I was able to implement it, but the output shows the wrong values. Here's what I did:

```
var myColor = new Colors();
var hslColor = myColor.convertColor({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
}, 'hsv2hsl');
```

**Output**

> Object {h: 100, s: -1.0204081632653061, l: -4900}

It's definitely doable as we see in the [convertionTest](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L478) function at [line 517](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L517) they did the same thing as I. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myColor = new Colors();

var hslColor = myColor.convertColor({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
}, 'hsv2hsl');
console.log(hslColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the names should be in all caps:

```js
var myColor = new Colors();

var hslColor = myColor.convertColor({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
}, 'HSV2HSL');
console.log(hslColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>
```